# while scrolling on a website with a keyboard chrome is behaving like a text file..how to prevent it

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, frontend

I think so this issue creates after a new update in chrome. While scrolling it behaves like a text file and the text editor pointer points to every image and text.
How to prevent it with CSS/js? [You can see text pointer in first row 5th box's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1gGg.png)
(on my side this is happening on all sites in chrome including StackOverflow).
or visit my site in chrome https://lazy-hazine.vipchauffeur.tk/#/

[can you see the black line before the lions' image?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PsRQ.png)

Comment: make your example reproducible, or link to the site

Comment: site link attached. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I checked your site and it looks good. I did not see the problem described by you on the site. Checked chrome on the browser.

Comment: you can check the new image.. black line before the image of lions..looks like I am in a text file. this line (pointer) blinks like a text editor

Comment: this issue I am facing since yesterday happening on all websites in chrome only.